# Convert text data to a single float number for a svc fit

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to learn ML on a tweet.

I convert the tweets via

```
df['vectorised_words'] = vectorizer.transform(df.tweet)
```

which gives me a `pandas.core.series.Series` and my vectorizer is `CountVectorizer`

My `X` and `Y` are the following:

```
X = df['vectorised_words']
y = df['is_hate_speech'].astype(int)
```

where X is a text (e.g. `"This is a sample tweet"`) and `Y` is a boolean - `True` or `False`.

Then I want to run the following:

```
svc_1 = SVC(kernel='linear')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state=46)
svc_1.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

However, the fit function gives the following error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'csr_matrix'
```

If I sum the array to a float, I think the conversion logic will be lost. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are trying to put a whole sparse matrix into a single pandas dataframe column, which is not the way to go.

Simply define your `X` as

```
X = vectorizer.transform(df.tweet.values)
```

and you should be fine.